# DataTable plugin, sort by drop down column

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTable plugin to manipulate data. 2 columns display drop down fields. I have enabled column sorting and table filtering.

I could sort all the columns except drop down fields columns. Similarly, search doesn't work in drop down fields columns.

I couldn't find any help on datatables for it.

To filter, the only option I could see now is to use like this 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Is there any other possibility?

Comment: Please add a minimal, complete and verifiable example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and present your experiment inside JSFiddle or StackOverflow's built in JS editor.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hint @Daniel
My question is actually answered in 2 different posts. I wanted to add sorting of form input fields in dataTable & also wanted filter to be avaialble for the same.

Sorting of data of input fields is explained at             `http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html`

& Filtering of data in input fields is explained at     `http://jsfiddle.net/3xm5nz95/`

I merged them & updated this fiddle. Below is the update fiddle url. 
    http://jsfiddle.net/3xm5nz95/23/

Hope this would help someone.

Best Regards
Uma